# android Trust anchor for certification path not found. My backend have not self assigned certificate. What to do?

Tags: android, ssl

My backend server can be accessed only by https. The certificate was bought/configured from a certificate authority (CA).
When I am trying to access my API through retrofit, I am getting error
`W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.`

The certificate which is configured on backend, I can not just put into my app. Then everyone using my app, can hack into and steal it.

What to do?

Comment: "Then everyone using my app, can hack into and steal it" -- only to the same extent that anyone with a Web browser can "steal" it. SSL certificate information is used by clients all the time. It is where the browser gets the details that it shows when you click the lock icon (or the equivalent) to get security details of the exception. "The certificate was bought/configured from a certificate authority (CA)" -- which one? Perhaps somebody will have some specific advice regarding that supplier.

Comment: as its not self assigned the system CAs should do the job. https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config

Comment: facing same issue and seems like problem is this for me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64605121/openssl-giving-kubernetes-ingress-controller-fake-certificate

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that on backend Intermediate certificate was not. So this problem has been solved.
Here is more info
https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/6398