# openssl giving Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, kubernetes-ingress

I have configured ssl certificate, if I visit `https://<domain>.com`, I see that my certificate is configured successfully but when I try to check certificate by following command

```
openssl s_client -connect <domain>.com:443 | openssl x509 -noout -subject -issuer
```

i am getting `Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate`

My ingres config is :

```
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect: 'true'
  name: nginx-echo
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - domain.com
      secretName: domain.com
  rules:
    - host: domain.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
                name: website-lorem
                port:
                    number: 80
```

with command gives the same fake certificate:
`openssl s_client -connect <domain>.com:443 -servername <domain> | openssl x509 -noout -subject -issuer`

Logs:

```
 6 flags.go:205] Watching for Ingress class: nginx
W1029 22:02:36.331841       6 flags.go:210] Ingresses with an empty class will also be processed by this Ingress controllernginx
W1029 22:02:36.332409       6 flags.go:252] SSL certificate chain completion is disabled (--enable-ssl-chain-completion=false)
W1029 22:02:36.332525       6 client_config.go:552] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
I1029 22:02:36.332855       6 main.go:231] Creating API client for https://<ip>:443
I1029 22:02:36.342532       6 main.go:275] Running in Kubernetes cluster version v1.19 (v1.19.2) - git (clean) commit f57430*** - platform linux/amd64
I1029 22:02:36.470142       6 main.go:105] SSL fake certificate created /etc/ingress-controller/ssl/default-fake-certificate.pem
I1029 22:02:36.472357       6 main.go:113] Enabling new Ingress features available since Kubernetes v1.18
W1029 22:02:36.476751       6 main.go:125] No IngressClass resource with name nginx found. Only annotation will be used.
I1029 22:02:36.485119       6 ssl.go:528] loading tls certificate from certificate path /usr/local/certificates/cert and key path /usr/local/certificates/key
I1029 22:02:36.544518       6 nginx.go:263] Starting NGINX Ingress controller
```

Comment: cuz of this android system certificates can not verify it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64600587/android-trust-anchor-for-certification-path-not-found-my-backend-have-not-self

Comment: Can you try adding -servername:  `openssl s_client -connect <domain>:443 -servername <domain> | openssl x509 -noout -subject -issuer` and see if it works?

Comment: @thomas gives still fake certificate

Answer (score 5):

Problem was that

1. `--default-ssl-certificate` flag was not set. More details can be found [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/#default-ssl-certificate)
2. `Intermediate certificate` was not set. Please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45796058/11148139) for more details.

Now its working.

There is also a [Github thread](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/6398) with this issue.

Comment: What certificate did you use for `--default-ssl-certificate` and intermediate certificate? I have no clue which certs to use there. My issue is exactly as yours for a subdomain e.g. `ex.example.com`. It shows a let's encrypt certificate via browser but openssl shows a fake k8s cert...

Comment: @user8462556 Can you explain more about these steps like where do you put `--default-ssl-certificate` flag.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the order of certificate chain was incorrect. I had appended the client certificate at the end. However it should be added at the top of the chain like mentioned below.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
{Client Certificate issued to you}
-----END CERTIFICATE-------
---BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
{Intermediate certificate}
-----END CERTIFICATE-------
---BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
{Root certificate}
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Above order for the chain is very critical..
Ensure that its in the same order and no keys are duplicated.

In  above scenario  - client certificate and chain is appended together (sometimes client certificate is uploaded/installed separately)